# I need to remove the selector boxes dynamically depeding on the value of another column in an interacrtive grid Oracle APEX 20.2

Tags: javascript, oracle, javascript-objects, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2

These are the boxes im referring to

[image: Boxes],

These are an apex item that ive added through the SQL query in which i create the table, [image: The item which gets created from my query]

which ive set to Row selector, As you can see it dosent have a client side condition so that dosnt work, it also cannot accept a STATIC ID for javascript so you have to go and find it which i have done.
Ive had a hard time making the item disappear, ive tried both Function and Global Variable Declaration in page JavaScript options as well as the JavaScript Initialization Code in the chart region, Ive also tried adding dynamic actions to execute javascript code

```
try {
    var columnValue = apex.region("Nivel_Reposicion").widget().interactiveGrid("getActions").getSelectedRecords()[0].data.Nivel_Reposicion;
    var showGrid = columnValue == "Sobrestock";
    var selectorGrid = apex.region("stock_ig_grid_vc_cur").widget();
    if (showGrid) {
        selectorGrid.show();
    } else {
        selectorGrid.hide();
    }
```

but nothing seems to work
Any solutions or recomendations you have im open to hearing them
Thank you in advance
Matias

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve ? I mean the business problem, not the technical solution that you have in mind.

Comment: Hey! so the logic is, this is a stock control chart, when you have less stock in the deposit than you should, or when the stock is badly positioned (as in not in the place its assigned to be) you can check the boxes to fire a creation of tasks to fix the problem, however the 3rd problem which the chart display is when you are overstocked and we wouldnt want the users to have the option to click those since you dont want to replace the item only know that theres too much of it. I can filter it on the pl side and is probably what ill do till someone comes up with a way to not show the checkboxes

Comment: Update: So ive tried the regular checkboxes and didnt work too well neither did the switch for my case, I am now using the standard APEX$ROW_SELECTOR item but still having the same problem of having to filter out all of the overflow items both in the apex table as in giving an error, I've processed it all this way and its a working workaround I'm leaving this post open in case someone finds a way to dynamically not show this selector boxes my best hope is Oracle sees this and gives us some more support for  the checkbox item in Interactive Grids.

Answer (score 0):

The row selector is heavily integrated with the IG model - don't think you have control over it, but from your description it seems you want to stop the user from doing something (in your case selecting the row) when a value in a column has a certain value. There are a couple of declarative options:

- On page load you can use an "allowed row operations" column to indicate if a row can be updated. This will not hide the row selector checkbox, but the row can not be updated or deleted (depending on the configuration).
- Use a custom column of type "Switch". This can be then disabled/enabled in a dynamic action. A column of type checkbox doesn't seem to support the dynamic action enabling/disabling

Hiding a control in an IG row is not something I have seen before - I wonder what kind of functionality you're expecting when a user saves an interactive grid with a hidden control. Enabling/disabling is probably the way to go and indicates very well to the customer (1) what the value is in the cell and (2) if he can update or not.

--UPDATE--

With the additional info that you passed in the comments, this is how you could approach it.

- Add a custom column of type "Checkbox" - do NOT use the ROWSELECTOR for this
- Use the "Allowed Row Operations" to have a NULL value for the rows with overstock and "U" for the other rows. That way the rows with overstock will be greyed out. If the other columns of the rows can be updated in case of overstock, then use a dynamic action on page initialization with a column of switch type as described above
- Use custom DML to process the IG on submit (which you probably are already doing)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer, Ill try the Switch type columns out and see how they feel. What you said i seem like i want to do is exactly it but to answer to the below comments im making an application to send a re stock order for the products checked, which will connect through a button clicked into plsql and do the rest from there, however, though i could filter it on the server side, ideally i dont want the user to be able to send a request when an item is Overstocked since theres already too much.